# how to add SP to entity frame work if that is not returning any value

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to add SP to entity framework.That has just update query.

steps 1 : I added SP to entity frame work.

steps 2 : I used Model Browser to add a Function Import. My SP returning  nothing. so I clicked none button in Function import form.

step 3 : I build project.

Doubts :

1. what about domain service for that SP.

   2.If we add any table to entity ...in Domain service class showing as a entity but not for SP. why so...

Is need any thing to add for SP in domain service class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation on using Stored procedure in EF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/gg699321.aspx